# Method to change colour of widget loaded via javascript

Tags: jquery, css, widget

My webpage includes some external javascript (the MET Office weather widget to be precise), which loads some HTML into the page.

I've tried changing the widget colour using jQuery to change the css of particular bits once the page has loaded, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div#location').css('color', 'red !important');
    });
</script>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: check the change you have made above using firebug, see if it works, otherwise something lower down in the dom has a style that will override your value...

Comment: When is the met office widget actually loaded onto the page? before document.ready or via an ajax call later?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#location').css({'color':'#f00'});
```

Also remember, if you have elements styled within the div they may override the styling of the container.
A better solution would be to create css rules and just apply a class the the JS loaded content

JS:

```
    $('#location').addClass('my-awesome-color-class');
```

CSS:

```
    .my-awesome-color-class,
    .my-awesome-color-class a, 
    .my-awesome-color-class p { color: #f00 !important } /* ans so on and so forth */
```

Comment: This doesn't work I'm afraid. Just noticed the javascript widget is inserting as an iFrame rather than directly into my page - is there anyway to change the CSS within an external page?

Comment: Not unless the iframe uses the same domain as you do, or you have access to the iframes page (code access), or the widget allows additional styling via parameters.